# Aggregations on high cardinality metrics

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a metric with a large cardinality so when I attempt to do something like this

```
histogram_quantile(0.99, sum(rate(http_request_duration_bucket[15d])) by (le, slo, job, namespace))
```

I get the error `query processing would load too many samples into memory in query execution`

What is the appropriate way of dealing with something like this?

The label(route) which is causing the high cardinality is not needed for this query, so I attempted to create a recording rule to remove all of the unnecessary labels

```
{
    expr: 'sum(http_request_duration_bucket) by (le, slo, job, namespace, pod)',
    record: 'http_request_duration_bucket:slo',
}
```

but the issue with this approach is that I will then be running a "rate" on a "sum".

Ideally I would "rollup" my aggregations with recording rules, something like

```
[{
  expr: 'histogram_quantile(0.99, sum(rate(http_request_duration_bucket[1m])) by (le, slo, job, namespace))',
  record: 'http_request_duration:99p:1m'
},
{
  expr: 'histogram_quantile(0.99, http_request_duration:99p:1m[1h])) by (le, slo, job, namespace))',
  record: 'http_request_duration:99p:1h'
},
{
  expr: 'histogram_quantile(0.99, http_request_duration:99p:1h[1d])) by (le, slo, job, namespace))',
  record: 'http_request_duration:99p:1d'
}]
```

but this produces some funky results.

What is the correct way of dealing with something like this in prometheus?

Comment: Try executing the original query in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics). It is optimized for performance, so, hopefully, the heavy query should work there without additional efforts and/or tuning.

Comment: You could reduce the number of data points being aggregated on by discarding those you already know you're not going to be interested in. If you are calculating an average of counters you can exclude `0` values, for instance. For percentiles of http request durations I have no idea...